# How to (if possible) get the reference of an in-memory object (class instance)?

Tags: debugging, reflection, scripting, abap

I'm trying to see if there's a way to get a refference of an object which is outside the local (and global) scope, but who exists in memory.

Let's say in my program, i've instantiated an object whose reference is this:
{O:9*\PROGRAM=ZAVG_DELETE_THIS\CLASS=LCL_SMTH}

Far away after tons of calls, in a context where i wouldn't be able to access this object, could i do something like getting the reference of this object simply by knowing the above string?

I was looking into the cl_abap_*descr classes, but i haven't found a method that takes the 'program_name', 'class_name' and 'instance_number', to return the reference of an object.

I'm trying to do this for the purpose of debugging, not to build something that works.

[EDIT 1]:
I assumed that the o:9 string was required in order to get the reference of the object. As pointed out in the response of @mydoghasworms, this isn't the case. It seems that i only need the local name of the variable which holds the reference.

Comment: I sincerely hope that this is impossible...

Comment: Not only is it possible (as I will shortly demonstrate), but it actually comes in quite handy! (Though I don't know what you mean by "for the purpose of debugging" - hope I understand you correctly!)

Comment: @mydoghasworms: You're not solving the question stated, see comment below.

Comment: Yes, now that you point it out. @vlad-ardelean, what would be the practical application of this? How would you even know the string in a program further down when it may always be different? (The O:9 reference is not guaranteed to be the same).

Comment: @mydoghasworms - though i don't know if the o:9 reference will be the same, i do expect "something" to be the same, because i expect the object to remain in the same memory location, regardless of the current stack position - so then i should generalize the question. thx for pointing this out

Comment: No problem. But your question is a very interesting one. I have been searching for a while now to find out if what you originally asked can be done, and I think it must be possible, because the debugger can translate that string into a reference. However, what is interesting to note is that the name of the type/class in the string is of no consequence. It is the number which seems to point to a reference on the heap. You can for instance put 9<> as the field name in the debugger and it will return the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly, because I am not sure what you mean with "for the purpose of debugging", but here goes:

You can access the variables of another program that are loaded in the memory of the same session (I am pretty sure it does not need to be in the call stack) using:

```
ASSIGN ('(PROGRAM)VARIABLE') TO LV_LOCAL.
```

With reference variables, it becomes a bit more tricky, but here is an example that will help to demonstrate.

Here is our calling program that contains a reference variable `LR_TEST` which we want to access somewhere else. For the purpose of the demonstration, I make reference to a locally defined class (because that's what I gather from your question).

```
REPORT  ZCALLER.

class lcl_test definition.
  public section.
    data: myval type i.

    methods: my_meth exporting e_val type i.
endclass.

data: lr_test type ref to lcl_test.

CREATE OBJECT lr_test.

lr_test->MYVAL = 22.

perform call_me(zcallee).

class lcl_test implementation.
  method my_meth.
* Export the attribute myval as param e_val.
    e_val = myval.
  endmethod.
endclass.
```

Here is the program in which we want to access a variable from the above program.

```
REPORT  ZCALLEE.

form call_me.

  field-symbols: <ref>.
  data: ld_test type ref to object.
  data: lv_val type i.

* Exhibit A: Gettinf a reference to a 'foreign' object instance
  assign ('(ZCALLER)LR_TEST') to <ref>.
* <ref> now contains a reference to the class instance from the program
* ZCALLER (not very useful, except for passing around maybe)

* Exhibit B: Getting a public attribute from a 'foreign' class instance
  assign ('(ZCALLER)LR_TEST->MYVAL') to <ref>.
* <ref> now contains the value of the attribute MYVAL

* Exhibit C: Getting a reference to an instance and calling a method
  assign ('(ZCALLER)LR_TEST') to <ref>. "Again the class reference
  if sy-subrc = 0. "Rule: Always check sy-subrc after assign before
                   "accessing a field symbol! (but you know that)
    ld_test = <ref>. "Now we have a concrete handle
* Now we make a dynamic method call using our instance handle
    CALL METHOD ld_test->('MY_METH')
      IMPORTING
        e_val = lv_val.
  endif.
endform.
```

Comment: By the way, this does not work if the latter program is called somewhere along the line using SUBMIT because it gets executed in a separate internal session, and therefore loses the context of the original session, so just watch out for that!

Comment: I know of that "backdoor", but this does not answer the original question because you need to have a static variable that refers to the instance. You can't use this technique to access an arbitrary instance by its "instance ID".

Comment: Ah yes, now that I read the question again, I understand a bit better.

Comment: this is good enough - i assumed that the instance ID is what is required for me to get the reference of the object. Now i see that i actually only need the variable name.